# Use htmlhelper to get action in BeginForm() Method of ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

In ASP.NET MVC 3 we always use `using(@html.BeginForm(){ }` helper (assume using without any parameters) to use forms with postback.

The returned html, includes an open `form` tag with some attributes and `action` that represent the postback url.

So when I overwrite my custom `BeginForm` helper I need this Url. This `action` attribute is not just action name or combination of `{area}/{controller}/{action}`.

I think this is a same url we use to see the current page, because when we submit page we backed to the same action or same action name with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

So how can I get this value from `HtmlHelper`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you need a custom BeginForm for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ILSpy or any other reflector and see what is happening in Html.BeginForm

I just copy paste the code for you.

```
// System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions
/// <summary>Writes an opening &lt;form&gt; tag to the response. When the user submits the form, the request will be processed by an action method.</summary>
/// <returns>An opening &lt;form&gt; tag. </returns>
/// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    string rawUrl = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
    return htmlHelper.FormHelper(rawUrl, FormMethod.Post, new RouteValueDictionary());
}


// System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions
private static MvcForm FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);
    bool flag = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;
    if (flag)
    {
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormIdGenerator());
    }
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    MvcForm result = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    if (flag)
    {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good answer.  You should probably mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an action attribute from @Html.BeginForm() without any parameters you can use jquery. I use this to ajax post a form inside jqueryUI dialogs.

```
var form = $('form'); //get the form
var actionUrl = $('form').attr('action'); //get the action url
```

And then you can use POST

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: actionUrl,
      data: form.serialize(),                                    
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                if (data.Sucess) {
                   //do something
               } else {
               }
      }
})
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

use htmlhelper argument

```
public class myBeginForm : IDisposable
{
    private HtmlHelper _myHtmlhelper;
    public myBeginForm (HtmlHelper htmlHelper, [you can add your need argument here] )
    {
        _myHtmlhelper= htmlHelper;
        var container = new TagBuilder("form");

       /// your Code 
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myHtmlhelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("</form>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add any argument, I mentioned at the question, I need to get value from `htmlhelper`, I am sure there is any way to get it, as you see `BeginForm()` get it