# How do I hide an element in the shared layout based on the controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar at the top of my page main page and inside it is a text input. I want it hidden until a search is performed and the user sees the results in the `results` controller .

This is inside my bootstrap navbar.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

For example:

```
Hidden:  www.example.com/home/index
Visible: www.example.com/results
```

Comment: One possible option would be to assign a value to `ViewBag` and include/exclude the html based on its value - `@if(ViewBag.CanDisplay) {..`

Comment: Since your `navbar` is on master/layout page...why not to check the condition there and display the input accordingly.

Comment: How would I check the condition on the master page/layout?

Comment: So this has nothing to do with bootstrap perse, the question is two part.  **1.** How to pass info from a controller to the shared layout, and **2** How to toggle the visibility of an element based on a property.  What have you tried so far regarding either of those?

Comment: I'm using @if(ViewBag.CanDisplay) to hide data currently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you actually don't need to pass any specific information from the controller to the shared layout.

The shared layout can inspect the current route and the behave accordingly.

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "results")
{
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
}
```

**More Info**:

- [Passing data to Master Page in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78548/1366033)
- [Get Current View's Url with HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10073894/1366033)
- [How to show/hide an area within Razor View in ASP.NET MVC programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6848055/1366033)